# handle more than one form in the multi document interface

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new to WinForms
my Main form is multi document interface and there is a new button when i click it
Form2 open up (I can open more than one form of type Form2 at the same time)

inside Form2 I have a data Grid View

the question is  how can I send any data from any class in the namespace to the data Grid View in Form2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5foXG.png)

Answer (score 0):

From *any class*?

I'd use an app-internal message bus, and have the forms subscribe to it and update things as they like.

Googling a bit, it looks like [TinyMessenger](https://github.com/grumpydev/TinyMessenger) could be a good option for the message bus. Borrowing e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/8560275/51685 for an usage example,

```
void OnReceiveDataSomewhere(byte[] data) {
    messageHub.Publish(new DataMessage(data));
}
```

```
class Form2 {
    // ...
    messageHub.Subscribe<DataMessage>((m) => { UpdateGrid(m.Data); });
```

Comment: I have used TinyMessenger for such tasks, and it works well.